# pdfbox generate pdf with cyrillic characters

Tags: java, pdfbox

I create pdf using pdfbox - 2.0.6, import custom font and fulfill the document with cyrillic characters. When i test on 3 computers(2xWindows based and 1 Linux ubunto based) it`s ok. But when i deploy my code to the server(CentOS based) the code trow this exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+0448 in font FontSans-BoldCyr`

I tried with pdfbox default fonts `(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN , PDType1Font.HELVETICA)` but then i get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0412 ('Vecyrillic') is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.encode(PDType1Font.java:345)
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:286)
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:411)
```

The text that i try to wrоte on the pdf is `"Вашето индивидуално предложение"`.

Comment: Have you read the FAQ? https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#fontencoding ? If yes, did you use `PDType0Font.load()` to load the font? If yes, then it means that the glyph isn't in the font. Use a different font, or copy the font from an OS where it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ms fonts packages on CentOS server and use them:
http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-microsoft-truetype-fonts-in-centos-6-rhel-6.html

Comment: If i install that package and use for example PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN can i write cyrrilic words?

Comment: No because it's not part of WinAnsiEncoding.

Comment: Just install DejaVu Sans, PT Sans, or better the @fonts group. If you want to manipulate fonts server-side do not build cut-down systems without fonts ! Default i18n Centos support is good, when left alone.